# ¿Dónde se usa "fama" como sinónimo de carnicería? ¿Cuál es el origen de la palabra?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, diferencias-regionales, colombia

Acabo de ver [en Twitter](https://twitter.com/cejaspobladas/status/288469825301389313) a una persona utilizando la palabra *fama* como sinónimo de *carnicería* (donde uno compra la carne):

> Crea *fama* y te sacarán fiada la carne.

En Colombia está bien decir:

> Voy a la *fama* a comprar churrasco.

Pero está en desuso.

Me preguntaba si en algún otro país se le conoce como sinónimo de carnicería y si además alguien sabe de dónde provino este uso.

El Diccionario de la RAE no muestra ningún indicio de que en algún otro país, ni siquiera Colombia, se le use como sinónimo de carnicería.

Algunos enlaces relevantes:

- [EL ESPAÑOL HABLADO EN COLOMBIA Y SU ATLAS LINGÜÍSTICO](http://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/thesaurus/pdf/18/TH_18_002_020_0.pdf) (pag 288) del Centro Virtual Cervantes.
- Una carnicería [que se llama "La Fama"](http://www.portal-bajacalifornia.com/regional/dir/carnicerias.html), en Tijuana. (Me llama la atención el nombre:  "La Fama")
- En Yahoo respuestas consultaron [¿porque en Colombia le dicen fama a las carnicerías?](http://espanol.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090927201242AA8G1Ar), pero no hay respuesta.

Comment: Buena pregunta. He escuchado que fama también se dice en Honduras y talvez en El Salvador. Talvez eso te dé otros indicios.

Comment: @Joze interesante. Mi búsqueda en Google no me mostró ningún indicio de que se usara en Honduras ni en El Salvador. Encontré algunos enlaces en páginas de México y un par de enlaces en Argentina pero ninguno era claro en si `fama` se usaba, o no, como sinónimo de `carnicería`. Parece bien enredado el asunto... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xyp7xt-ygy0

Comment: Nunca lo he oído en Argentina.

Comment: Yo lo he oído solamente en Colombia. Como me resultó extraño pregunté de donde venía el término, pero lamentablemente mi interlocutor lo desconocía.

Comment: En Nicaragua no la usamos de esa forma tampoco..

Comment: Tampoco lo usamos así en Chile

Comment: La primera carnicería de Bogotá se llamaba la fama y de ahí su origen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ¿Por qué los bogotanos llamamos fama a las carnicerías?
>
> Por Jairo Pedraza
>
> Vivimos en el siglo XXI y aun hay muchas personas que le dicen "fama" a las carnicerías, una costumbre muy colombiana, pero antes que eso, muy bogotana. Esta es la razón: en el siglo XIX, cuando el abasto de carnes en Bogotá se limitaba a cuatro carnicerías, una de ellas tenía el nombre de Carnicería La Fama. Las otras eran, Carnicería de las Nieves, Carnicería de Santa Bárbara y Carnicería de San Victorino. La Carnicería La Fama tuvo el acierto de adquirir directamente el ganado a los campesinos, omitiendo de esa manera los intermediarios, por lo cual sus precios eran muy competitivos y en poco tiempo se convirtió en la carnicería favorita de los bogotanos de la época. Poco a poco, expresiones como "ir a la fama" o "yo compro en la fama"  fueron enraizándose en la cultura popular, hasta el punto de llamar fama a todas las carnicerías que poco a poco surgieron.
>
> Aun en el año 2021, le seguimos llamando fama a un expendio de carne.

(fuente: [Historia y Antiguedades de Colombia, Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/HistoriaAntiguaColombia/posts/237671697918222))

Comment: ¡excelente dato! respuesta aceptada. ¿Podría explicar quién es Jairo Pedraza o de dónde provino ese escrito que acaba de poner?

Comment: Jairo Pedraza fue quien dio la respuesta en otro chat... yo copie y le doy el crédito

Comment: Entiendo pero, ¿se puede enlazar la discusión del chat al que te refieres?

Answer (score 9):

Creo que puede ser un caso de [vulgarización de marca](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marca_vulgarizada) a partir del nombre de los [supermercados "La Fama"](http://www.lafama.cl/).

Buscando en Google veo que, además, hay muchos supermercados y establecimientos de venta de comida que se llaman "Fama" o "La Fama" en Colombia y otros países vecinos. No sé si esto es causa o efecto de la expresión en la OP.

Comment: Esta es una buena teoría; sin embargo debo anotar dos cosas: `1.` El enlace del supermercado "La Fama", es de Chile, no de Colombia, y en Chile no se usa `Fama` como sinónimo de carnicería (ver comentario de Dusan). `2.` Jamás he visto un supermercado -al menos importante- con ese nombre en Colombia. Dicho lo anterior, la teoría de César no es, en todo caso, inverosímil, pues pudieron haber existido mucho antes, por lo que le doy un +1 por el momento.

Answer (score 6):

El Diccionario de americanismos indica dónde se usa:

> [**fama**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=rS8rckuN4x0AITGEsDF).
>   I.  1.  f. Co:C,E. Tienda o lugar donde se vende la carne al por menor.
>   II. 1.  f. Bo. Disparo que se da en el centro del blanco.

Es decir, en el centro y el este de Colombia.

Comment: El origen sigue siendo incierto, pero es cierto que sólo se usa en el centro y oriente de Colombia. En Antioquia no lo usamos.

Answer (score 3):

La verdad de que se use "Fama" como sinónimo a carnicería en Colombia es que en el siglo XIX existió una carnicería en el centro de Bogotá que se llamaba "La Fama", y era la única de aquel entonces, por lo que la expresión "voy a La Fama", o "hijo, vaya a La Fama", se quedó guardada para siempre en la cultura Bogotana.

Comment: Bienvenido Eduardo. ¿Tienes alguna referencia al respecto? Además de adicionar una referencia si la tienes creo que es bueno que aclares que no se usa en toda Colombia.

Comment: @DGaleano no hay ningún equivalente en Antioquia? ¿O se dice _carnicería_ sin más?

Comment: @fedorqui no tenemos equivalente para *fama* en Antioquia. Simplemente *carnicería*

Answer (score 2):

No voy a aportar fuentes porque me quitaría mucho tiempo buscarlas. Dudo de que "fama" provenga de un establecimiento colombiano porque ¿cómo es que se dice en Honduras? Por el mismo motivo dudo del origen árabe, ¿por qué sólo en el centro de Colombia, donde la inmigración árabe es mucho menor que en muchos otros sitios? Yo supongo otra cosa, para la que me baso en el hecho curioso de que ciertas gentes de Honduras y Costa Rica tienen un acento muy parecido al de Bogotá, a pesar de la distancia. Yo creo que "fama" es un muisquismo, y está documentado que en ciertas zonas de Centroamérica se hablaban lenguas chibchas. La documentación sobre esas lenguas es escasa y difícil de encontrar, pero es característico que las palabras reconocidas ("cuba", "picho", "pichar") sean muy usuales en el altiplano del centro de Colombia y no en el resto del país. A lo mejor algún hondureño, salvadoreño o costarricense encuentra en su idiolecto palabras parecidas.

Comment: "No voy a aportar fuentes porque me quitaría mucho tiempo buscarlas", ya pero eso es lo que diferencia una buena contribución de una que no lo es. Respaldar lo explicado en tu contribución con las fuentes apropiadas haría que la gente dijese "pues tiene razón, debe ser así" en lugar de preguntarse "cómo sé que no es solo su opinión o que se lo está inventando?" Visita [tour], [help] y [answer] si quieres saber más sobre como funciona [Spanish.se] y qué modelo seguimos, en especial para motivar respuestas documentadas.

Answer (score 0):

Haciendo la misma investigación encontré este post y una teoría que tengo es que la palabra derivó del árabe, donde "laHm" significa carne, la pronunciación de esa "h" es bastante fuerte.

Se me ocurre que cuando los inmigrantes árabes llegaron a Colombia usaban esta palabra que luego en español colombiano derivó en "la fama" por como sonaba.

Comment: ¡Excelente teoría! Gracias por la respesta. +1

Answer (score 0):

Soy colombiano, conozco toda la región caribe, soy antioqueño, y también conozco el eje cafetero, valle del cauca, Cauca y Nariño y puedo asegurar que en mis cuarenta años de vida ¡JAMÁS! escuché que alguien le dijera "fama" a la carnicería.

En cambio en Ecuador sí lo escuché, pero pensé que era el nombre específico de alguna. Para resumir, puedo deducir que ese nombre no es colombiano y de hecho es poco usado en Colombia, de pronto en algún pueblo o departamento específico lo usen, no sé, pero no se puede asegurar que es un término colombiano.